# Ubuntu - * at the end of filename?

Tags: ubuntu-10.10, ls

In Ubuntu 10.10, showing a file listing using `ll` will occasionally show files with a * appended to the name of the file.  What does this star mean?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It means the file is [executable](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/General-output-formatting.html).

Answer (score 19):

It means the file is executable and you have `ll` aliased to `ls -F`, `ls --classify` or `ls --indicator-style=classify` (among other possible options). You can use the command `alias ll` to see what the alias is and change it persistently by editing your `~/.bashrc` file (or other file) where it's defined.

Other indicators:

- `/` - directory
- `@` - symbolic links
- `|` - fifos
- `=` - sockets
- `>` - doors

each depending on OS/filesystem support.